# Meteor: How to have JS date range picker adjust API call date parameters

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have data being pulled from the Google API which I am then trying to display on charts. Part of the params required for the API call are start-date" and "end-date". For this, I would like to use this bootstrap [date range picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) for users to be able to select these dates and then have it adjust the API call accordingly. To make the API call I am using this package: [percolate:google-api](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api).

Here is an example of the API call:

```
GoogleApi.get('youtube/analytics/v1/reports', { params: { 'end-date': "2015-10-31", metrics: "views", ids: "channel==MINE", 'start-date': "2015-10-01", metrics: "views", dimensions: "day", sort: "-day"}}, function(error, result) {
});
```

Here is my example for the date range selector:

```
Template.apps.rendered = function(){

$('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract(29, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
    endDate: moment(),
    showDropdowns: true,
    showWeekNumbers: true,
    timePicker: false,
    timePickerIncrement: 1,
    timePicker12Hour: true,
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    opens: 'left',
    drops: 'down',
    buttonClasses: ['btn', 'btn-sm'],
    applyClass: 'btn-primary',
    cancelClass: 'btn-default',
    separator: ' to ',
    locale: {
        applyLabel: 'Submit',
        cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
        fromLabel: 'From',
        toLabel: 'To',
        customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
        daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr','Sa'],
        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        firstDay: 1
    }
}, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), label);
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
});

};
```

I would like to have it so when the user first visits the page it is automatically set at "Last 30 Days", but then if they would like to choose a different date they can do so and have my API call update automatically.

How can I achieve this? Any code examples are greatly appreciated as I am fairly new to Meteor/JS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [reactive-vars](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) to set the value of your startDate, endDate, and whatever you're using to keep track of the API call result.  Then you can put the API call in a [Template.instance().autorun()](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) with a dependency on the startDate and endDate reactive variables..

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion, I've been trying to make this work using reactive variables for a few days now but unfortunately having no luck at it. Is there any chance you would have an idea/example of how this would look based on my shared code above?